# Snakemake: go back and clean up temp() files

Tags: snakemake

I know variants on this have been asked before (e.g. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/snakemake/4kslVBX2kew), but I don't see a definitive solution.

If I run a long-running and complex Snakemake pipeline with '--notemp' (maybe because I'm debugging), it would be really nice to be able to subsequently run a 'cleanup' command to delete anything that would automatically have been deleted on the first run without --notemp. Is there any easy way of doing this?

The way I'm doing this right now is to re-run after using '--forceall --touch', without '--notemp', such that everything just gets touched, and the temp files then get removed at the end. But it's not ideal to change all the timestamps. Is there a better way?

Jon

Comment: This is indeed a good idea. I will add a corresponding function once I find the time. I am also very open to pull requests.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll take a look at the code and see if it's something I can attempt myself, it would be good to be able to give something back to Snakemake.

Answer (score 2):

Since v5.0.0, `--delete-temp-output` achieves this.

```
--delete-temp-output


Remove all temporary files generated by the workflow. Use together with –dry-run to list files without actually deleting anything. Note that this will not recurse into subworkflows.

Default: False
```